# BASH: Bind Program's Existance to Another Program

Tags: bash, shell, application

I want to create a script that runs two programs.  That part's simple, but there's a catch: I want to kill the second one if the first one exits.  How can I do that?

**Edit**

I tried killing the program by it's PID after the other one exits, but the program is `hamster-time-tracker`, which is a Python application that exits immediately, apparently spawning another process.  How can I get around this?  Is there some way to get the other PID spawned?

**Edit 2**

Figured it out.  I had to run `python /usr/bin/hamster-time-tracker` instead of `hamster-time-tracker`, and it stayed running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd-a &
a=${!}

cmd-b &
b=${!}

wait $a
kill $b
```

I used `yes a` and `yes b` as commands when testing this.

Comment: +1 for an elegant solution that is easy to understand

Answer (score 3):

There's [wait](http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2008/06/bash-wait-command.html) command in the bash to wait for termination of first application and then kill second app.

Since waits are inserted automatically after commands not ending with &, the right order may save you from going into manual wait trouble:

```
A &
B          # waits
kill $!    # then kills A
```

Comment: you can find the pid of spawned process using ps aux | grep <name of you process> and then wait for it.

Comment: That's not robust in the case of running multiple copies of the same program.